# Using TCP for File Transfer Between Java (Android client) and C (PC server - Linux)

Tags: java, android, c, tcp, file-transfer

I know similar questions exist but I haven't found any of them suitable for my problem. I have an Android device (API 15 - Android version 4.0.4) and a Linux machine running Arch Linux. The idea was to create a connection between the server (C program) and client (Android app) so I could exchange files. Also, the server supports parallel connections and requires authentication. The android app has to create 3 connections to the server (using 3 different ports, so that means 3 AsyncTask-s running multi-threaded ) .. Two of them are for parallel background processes, and 1 is for the actual file transfer. I have created a code which worked well on the Emulator (Android KitKat OS), but when testing on my own phone it doesn't work. I will post my code, and I would like some advice from you, if that is possible. Thanks.

This is the code running on Android devices... BUFFSIZE
 is 1024 and it is a global variable.
I've tried setting it to many values and none of them worked for me. filesize is set earlier in the code and always has the correct value so don't worry about it :)

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(target);

int u;
byte[] jj = new byte[BUFFSIZE];
long overall = 0, percent = 0;

try {

     while (overall < filesize && mRun) {
           u = is.read(jj, 0, BUFFSIZE);
           if (u == -1) break;
           fs.write(jj, 0, u);
           overall += u;
           percent = overall*100/filesize;
     }

     fs.flush();
     fs.close();
     is.close();
     socket.close();

} catch (IOException ex) {
     // There were no exceptions while testing
     // There is some code here that deals with the UI
     // which is not important 
}
```

And this is the C code...

```
for (;;)
    {
        /* First read file in chunks of BUF_SIZE bytes */
        unsigned char buff[BUFFER]={0};
        int nread = fread(buffer,1,BUFFER, input);
        printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);

        /* If read was success, send data. */
        if(nread > 0)
        {
            printf("Sending \n");
            write(sockfd, buffer, nread);
        }

        /*
         * There is something tricky going on with read ..
         * Either there was error, or we reached end of file.
         */
        if (nread < BUFFER)
        {
            if (feof(input))
                printf("End of file\n");
            if (ferror(input))
                printf("Error reading\n");
            break;
        }
    }
```

I have tested this code many times, even using telnet and it worked quite well. But I am not sure about the Java code.

So, why doesn't it work? Well, what I know so far is that some files are damaged. Let's just say that if I transfer an mp3 file with the size of 4MB, 3.99 would be sent and the resting 0.01 would be lost somewhere in the middle of the file, for no reason! When you play the damaged mp3, you can realize that some parts (like, every 10 seconds) you go "off-beat".. Like if there was a small noise that is then skipped. The resulting file is shorter for around 10 000 bytes than the original (but that depends on the actual file size.. You always lose some small percentage of the file, and that means that the while loop never finishes - the download process never finishes because the sockets are blocking and the client ends up waiting for more bytes which are never received) .. What I believe that happens is that, from a 1024-byte-long buffer, around 1000 bytes are used sometimes, instead of the full 1024 buffer size, which leads to the loss of 24 bytes. I am not saying that these are the actual numbers, but, that is just something going on in my head; I am likely wrong about this. I couldn't share the whole code with you because it's really long, so I decided to use the functions that deal with the download process, instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally fine for the `read` method not to fill the whole buffer. That method returns the number of bytes read. You even assign that value to a variable:

```
u = is.read(jj, 0, BUFFSIZE);
```

But then you only check if `u` is `-1` in order to find out when to stop reading. From the documentation:

```
The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.
```

Which means that your byte array has a maximum length of 1024 bytes, but not all of those will be filled at each `read`. And of course it won't be, otherwise this would only work if your input stream contains an exakt multiple of 1024 bytes.

Also: a thing called `debugging` exists. It might be hard to inspect binary data such as mp3 files, so try debugging while transmitting a text file.

Comment: Yes, but why isn't my file received then? It works well with text files and when I debug it. It fails with somewhat larger files. It skips a few bytes from time to time. Let's just pretend that this is the whole file: 12345  .. It reads 123 and then 5 .. It skips the number 4 and when it comes to the end of the whole file, it hangs there because it expects more bytes to be read ( one more to be exact - number 4 ) .. This is what happens with large files and I cannot figure out where the actual problem is.